# What does Slavoj Zizek mean by Hegel's reading of "felix culpa"?

Tags: ethics, hegel, debate, zizek

Recently I watched "[The duel of the century](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=78BFFq_8XvM&t=8310s)" between Slavoj Zizek and Jordan Peterson.
Briefly in 2:17:45 min. Zizek points out to Hegel reading of "The story of the fall", a quote from Zizek

> This is how Hegel reads the story of the fall, that fall really is
>   "felix culpa",  in the sense that for Hegel, before the "fall" we are
>   simply animals, it's through the fall that you perceive goodness as
>   what will drag you out of the fall. ... It's not that you fall from
>   goodness, your fall retroactively creates what you fell from.

Being new to philosophy even the term "[felix culpa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Felix_culpa)" is new to me.
I have watched a lot of Zizek's talks, but haven't read one of his books yet.
Can you point me out to some books, articles, etc.. , where can I reed about this?

Reading Hegel directly would be too complex for me, but nonetheless I would like to know where does Hegel point out to this.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Felix Cupla" is the title of the third chapter in [Zizek's book *Event: A Philosophical Journey Through A Concept*](https://www.penguinrandomhouse.com/books/243017/event-by-slavoj-zizek/9781612194110/). I haven't read it myself but it looks like a good place to start.

Answer (score 1):

I think he is talking about Hegel's reading of "[The original sin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Original_sin)" and the idea (from naive point of view) is that men are not good in the beginning and then they fall from goodness, but that they are evil from the beginning.

A text from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fall_of_man) on the "Fall of men", sometimes referred to as "Felix culpa".

> The fall of man, or the fall, is a term used in Christianity to
>   describe the transition of the first man and woman from a state of
>   innocent obedience to God to a state of guilty disobedience.

I think Hegel refers to this reading of the "Original sin" in the [Lectures on the Philosophy of Religion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lectures_on_the_Philosophy_of_Religion).

There a lot of questions to be understood in this thought, for now, do to my knowledge, I can only refer to [Hegel Reads Genesis](https://www.academia.edu/8178247/Hegel_Reads_Genesis) article by Nicholas Adams, and the book that Brian Z pointed out.